# Grouping by a values of a column and return max

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with many columns. Now I want to group by values of a column and then return `max` of another specified column, and also return the values of the remaining columns corresponding to the rows where that `max` occurred. Below is one example

```
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['Y', 'Y', 'Z'] , 'X1' : [10, 20, 30], 'X2' : [11, 10, 20], 'X3' : [20, 15, 60]})
dat.groupby('A').agg({'X1' : 'max'})
   X1
A    
Y  20
Z  30
```

As you see it did not return other columns i.e. `X2, X3` etc. I want to get values of those column where the `max` occurred i.e. `{10, 15} and {20, 60}`. In column `X1`, there are no repeated values within a group. In my actual dataframe I have many columns so a general approach would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`idxmax` returns the index where the `max` appears, so we can make use of that by taking the whole row where `X1`'s max is in each group.

```
df.loc[df.groupby('A')['X1'].idxmax()]
```

Output:

```
   A  X1  X2  X3
1  Y  20  10  15
2  Z  30  20  60
```